# filter an array from mysql_query result by value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So... I am PHP dummie and I am trying to filter an array.

I have the following php function to retrieve data from MYSQL

```
function hook_plan1($vars){
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblpricing WHERE relid=12 AND type='product'");
  $products = array();
    while( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    array_push($products, $data);
    }
  return array(
  "plan1" => $products);
}
```

That function renders the following array:

```
->plan1 = Array (7)
  0 => Array (16)
    id => "71"
    type => "product"
    currency => "1"
    ...
  1 => Array (16)
    id => "80"
    type => "product"
    currency => "3"
    ...
  2 => Array (16)
    id => "402"
    type => "product"
    currency => "14"
    ...
```

I would like to filter that array by "currency" (which comes in the $_SESSION) so I can get a single array, something like this:

```
->plan1 = Array (16)
    id => "402"
    type => "product"
    currency => "14"
    ...
```

I was pretty sure it was easy, so I tried the following array filter:

```
function hook_plan1($vars){
  $currency_id = $_SESSION['currency'];//this is a number
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblpricing WHERE relid=12 AND type='product'");
  while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $products = $data;
  }
  $filter = (is_array($products) && $products['currency'] == $currency_id);
  $filtered_product = (array_filter($products, $filter));
  return array(
    "plan1" => $filtered_product);
}
```

But it doesn't work :(
Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just add that to the `WHERE` clause in the query?

Comment: `AND currency = '$currency_id'`

Comment: 1) your `$filter` is not a function, while it should be; 2) you attempt to filter `$data`, not `$products`.

Comment: ... and yes, it's far better to make this filtering on DB level.

Comment: ... provided you properly **ESCAPE** `$currency_id` when generating the SQL of course...

Comment: The database is pretty intricate, I am already using WHERE to filter 'relid=12' and AND to filter type="product" can I use it twice?

Comment: @ValerieCastle You can have as many `AND` as you want in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: oh... I am such a dummie, thanks it worked just adding AND currency = '$currency_id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments says, it's a lot better if you filter this in the mysql query:

```
$currency_id = (int)$_SESSION['currency'];//you should be REALLY sure this is a number
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblpricing WHERE relid=12 AND type='product' AND currency=$currency_id");
```

but if for some reason you definitely, absolutely, positively NEED to filter it in the PHP side, then you need to deliver a function that returns a function [insert Inception horn here], in other words your `$filter` variable should be:

```
$filter = function($currencyToFilter) {
        return function($arrayRow) use ($currencyToFilter) {
            return $arrayRow['type'] === $currencyToFilter;
        };
    };
```

That's a [Closure thingy](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php). Then you call (notice that i use `$products` instead of `$data`):

```
$filtered_product = array_filter($products, $filter($_SESSION['currency']));
```

Comment: Please *PLEASE* escape `$currency_id` before concatenating it into `$result`. One can never be sure enough.

Comment: Besides casting it (as i edited above) and using PDO, are there other ways to escape a number?

Comment: Yes a few: [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) (deprecated), [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), or, for numbers, the good old `sprintf('%d')` (e.g. `$query = sprintf('SELECT [...] AND currency_id = %d',$currency_id);`). PDO is best though.