# Get row number from response condition

Tags: php

Let's say I have the following:

```
$variable = SELECT * FROM `accounts` order by `creation_date`
```

The accounts table holds:

```
| id | username | creation_date | ...
```

If the `$variable` outputs the following:

Response:

```
| id | username | creation_date|
| 2 | bob      | 1             |
| 4 | jesus    | 2             |
| 8 | vanessa  | 4             |
| 5 | user1    | 43            |
```

Is it a good way to actually get how many rows that occurred in the $variable before that `Jesus`? In this case, it would be row number two in the query performed.

I do know other methods, like doing a `foreach` and check everyone for `jesus`, but I hope there is better solutions for this?

I'm going to on every page refresh, do this query, and find a persons row. So a foreach/while loop would be slow wouldn't it?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `accounts` where username = 'jesus'

Comment: @splash58 but i do not get the row of it from the spesific query...

Comment: i don't understand - do you want to get row by its sequential number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filter an array from mysql\_query result by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127797/filter-an-array-from-mysql-query-result-by-value)

Comment: based on any query, lets say my example $variable, i want to get the row number for ( example) jesus. how many rows thats before the row to jesus in that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit messy, but this should work. This uses an internal MySQL variable to add a rank column to each row in the table, and then selects that column from a sub-query based on the provided username.

```
Set @rank:=0;
Select rank
  From (
      Select username, @rank:=@rank+1 As rank
        From `accounts`
    Order By creation_date
  ) tbl
 Where username = 'Jesus';
```

PDO example:

```
$db->query('Set @rank:=0;');

$sql = "
  Select rank
    From (
        Select username, @rank:=@rank+1 as rank
          From `accounts`
      Order By creation_date
    ) tbl
 Where username = :username;
";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([':username' => 'Jesus']);

$rank = $stmt->fetch()['rank'];
```

Comment: `tbl cross join (Set @rank:=0) r` - to use with mysqli library

Answer (score 0):

You can use a count variable & increment while getting each row like in while loop as follows

```
$cnt=0;
while($obj=mysql_fetch_object($res))
{
$cnt++;
....
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but isnt it a better solution?